# Getting error "URI is not registered" for http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd

Tags: servlets, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Community Edition and Tomcat 6.0.53. Trying to display this bean - #{helloWorld.getMessage()}. This is the only thing on the page.

First of all, the () on the end of getMessage causes a hard runtime error. When I remove it and try outputting a field, like #{helloWorld.message}, everything runs but I get a blank screen.

I am getting the above message that the the URI is not registered which causes my servlet tags to not be recognized, which must be the problem. Just not sure how to register. I go to Schemas and DTDs but not sure what I'm supposed to input or select. Could someone walk me through this? Thanks.

A partial of my web.xml is attached below, where the URI message occurs.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:web = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       id = "WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>faces/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!--
   FacesServlet is main servlet responsible to handle all request.
   It acts as central controller.
   This servlet initializes the JSF components before the JSP is displayed.
-->

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

(partial code shown. servlet tags are red and cannot be resolved.)

Comment: Proper support for web technologies is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone corroborate this just to be sure? Has anyone used jsp like a managed bean in the Community edition?